# Enumerate all binary numbers of length n and weight at most k lexicographically

Tags: c, combinatorics

I'm looking for an algorithm which enumerates all binary numbers of a given length `n` lexicoraphically, with the constraint that every number is skipped, which has a hamming weight `> k`, for a given `k`.

For example: for `n=4` and `k=2`:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
---- skipped 
1000
1001
1010
---- skipped
1100
---- skipped
---- skipped
---- skipped
```

of course the most straight forward way would be to add 1 in every loop iterations and check if the hamming weight is over the threshold. But for larger `n` the number of elements you skip increases, so the overhead of checking every number is increasing too. So I'm also looking for an efficient way to do this.

Update:
I reemplented @500-internal-server-error in a iterative way as follows

```
uint64_t update_stack(uint32_t *stack, uint32_t *sp, const uint64_t n, const uint64_t k) {
    if (stack[*sp] == k) {
        uint32_t i = *sp + 1;

        // walk up
        while (stack[i] == k)
            i += 1;

        // update
        stack[i] += 1;
        const uint32_t val = stack[i];
        const uint32_t altered_sp = i;

        // walk down
        while (i > 0) {
            stack[i - 1] = val;
            i -= 1;
        }

        // fix up stack pointer
        *sp = 0;
        return (1ull << (altered_sp + 1)) - 1;
    } else {
        stack[*sp] += 1;
        return 1ull;
    }
}

void Generate(const uint64_t n, const uint64_t k) {
    uint32_t *stack = (uint32_t *)calloc(n-k+1, sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t sp = 0;

    uint64_t ctr = 0;
    while (ctr < (1ull << n)) {

        // number of k windows the algorithm walks through.
        const uint64_t limit = k+1-stack[sp];

        //print_stack(stack, n, k);

        for (uint64_t cw = limit; cw > 1; --cw) {

            // start printing
            const uint64_t nr_steps = (1ull << cw) - 1ull;
            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < nr_steps; ++i) {
                f(ctr++);
            }

            // skip
            const uint64_t nr_skip = update_stack(stack, &sp, n, k);
            ctr += nr_skip;
        }

        f(ctr++);

        const uint64_t nr_skip = update_stack(stack, &sp, n, k);
        ctr += nr_skip;
    }

    free(stack);
}
```

which was kinda hard, but it finally worked. I also added a [Benchmark](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/HZZJH82hYaLZL5rTJlUAccy-ylc), which shows for a simple function `f` which is applied for every valid value, how much the speedup compared to the naive way. For `n=20` and `k=3` its 150 times faster (depending on f).

Comment: Are you looking for Python or C++? Can you show your current attempt?

Comment: There is a [std::popcount](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount) in C++20.  That's why you should focus on one language, not two or three.

Comment: Probably easiest to just generate the bit possibilities for your constraints, e.g. `0000`, `0001`, `0011` then find all the possible permutations of those bits

Comment: So you're basically trying find a way to calculate the number of bits that would change from1 to 0 or from 0 to 1 by the `+1` operation. I'm not sure if it's possible do do such a thing that is more efficient than naively just counting the 1 bits for every number, especially as Python and C++20  have built-in operators for bit counting that are presumably quite efficient.

Comment: @AlanBirtles good idea, but there might be a lot of possibilities if `n` is large and the permutations need to be sorted as well.

Comment: @IainShelvington i added my approach in C. In theory i dont care in which language one uses, i will translate everything later to C++. The code i wrote is obviously to overstaded for the current problem instance. But think of `n=32` and `k=4`. Now most of the `2**n` vectors are invalid, and i only need to enumerate a few of them. Thats the reason i do not want to enumerate over all vectors and do a 'std::popcount', this is simply far to expensive.

Comment: @PingFloyd *But for larger n* -- What is the maximum value for `n`?  -- *this is simply far to expensive* -- And note, `std::popcount` will more than likely utilize the CPU for the popcount if it exists instead of counting bits, way faster than your hand-rolled version.

Comment: @PingFloyd *But think of n=32 and k=4. Now most of the 2**n vectors are invalid, and i only need to enumerate a few of them.* -- How many times in your application will you need to enumerate them, using `n=32` and `k = 4`?  If it's multiple times, you could use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.).  Sure, the first time around, you pay the price, but subsequent calls, you have all the values you need without recomputing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it recursively.

Here's an example in C# (sorry, I am not set up for doing c/c++ right now):

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Generate(int value, int onesLeft, int bitsLeft, int bits)
    {
        if (bitsLeft > 0)
        {
            Generate(value << 1, onesLeft, bitsLeft - 1, bits);
            if (onesLeft > 0)
                Generate((value << 1) + 1, onesLeft - 1, bitsLeft - 1, bits);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bits; i++)
            {
                Console.Write((value >> (bits - i) - 1) & 1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Generate(int bits, int maxOnes)
    {
        Generate(0, maxOnes, bits, bits);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Generate(4, 2);
    }
}
```

Output for Generate(4, 2):

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
1000
1001
1010
1100
```

Output for Generate(5, 1):

```
00000
00001
00010
00100
01000
10000
```

Comment: Nice answer, but is it really efficient for large values of `n` and `k`? It would be interesting to compare with the brute force method using an efficient builtin `popcount`.

Comment: Indeed. This was written with clarity in mind, not performance.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a realy nice and straight forward solution, I had a hard time translating into into a iterative algorihtms, but never the less it worked and its quite fast.